# Are there any gotchas for the blackberry webapps that use cookies?

Tags: browser, blackberry, cookies, mobile

I know I am not giving many details... It is hard to get many details right now...
but I am working on a web app, that has a login page, and stores if the user is logged in, in session data, that is linked to cookie data.

It works on most devices and computers...but on the blackberries I have tried it on, it seems to lose the cookie information, because after a user goes through the login workflow, the site still thinks they are not logged in.

Does anybody know of common gotchas or problems with using cookies on Blackberry devices?

I have been experimenting a bit, and my problem appears to be isolated to when cakePHP generates the session_id cookie, on blackberry devices.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't blackberry-specific, but it's not uncommon for the HTTP gateways of some mobile operators to drop cookies. For example, they can load-balance requests from devices across multiple gateways, and each request can spontaneously hop from one to the other, and you lose your cookies.

I would advise not using cookies if you want to play it safe, especially if you want your app to work across every network. Instead, use URL-rewriting to put the session ID into the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cakePHP was doing something (not sure what) that prevented cookies from working normally on blackberry devices.  We override cakePHP's session, by starting the session manually, and the session now work normally on blackberry devices.